# In Unity, how can I render borders of provinces from a colored province map in a grand strategy game?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, algorithm, maps

I am kind of a beginner of Unity and I am trying do work on a grand strategy game. I already have a province map, colored by unique rgba for each province, looks like something below:

[image: s]

I know that the province map is kind of a look up map for province id. But when I obverse the paradox strategy games, I notice that they have render borders differently for the provinces and nations. For example, in the CK3, the Baron collars are separated with dotted lines, and the kingdoms are separated with enhanced yellow lines.

[image]

I thought they have some other maps or files containing those information, so I went to read their dev diary, and I find that all province shape information are stored in the province map.

[image]

So, my question is:

Is there any way in Unity3D to create those different borders with some shader and some province map such those given above?

I think what I wish to accomplish is something as this link:
[Render border on 3D map](https://answers.unity.com/questions/679958/render-border-on-3d-map.html)

Which is:
[image]

Comment: I have did some thinking myself, I am now wondering if there is a method to add line on texture between any two color-blocks, the question can be solved.

Comment: If there are any way to manipulate color blocks in texture with shader, it would also be helpful.

Comment: By the way: Paradox grand strategy games are using an inhouse engine called Clausewitz which is specialized for map rendering. So they can use some low-level techniques which you don't have in Unity.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I am pretty aware of that. But there have to be so algorithm can do this. I mean, what they are using is just the province map, and returned with a model of line along the border. Although it could be expensive in Unity, it doesn't means this is impossible.